# How do SSD manufacturers gain competitive advantage?

Tags: ssd

Most SSD manufacturers (with some notable exceptions such as Samsung) just use off-the-shelf controllers and off-the-shelf NAND in their products.

How do these SSD companies get competitive advantage? i.e. do they bring something else to the table other than assembling components into one neat package?

Comment: I think you might need to prove your first claim. But assuming it is true, I think that their costs are relatively low and they can offer the product for a lower price. I don't see why there needs to be something "else on the table" rather than what it is.

Answer (score 1):

I think they sell out a reasonable percent of their capacity and their is enough demand to keep everyone happy. I don't really think any supplier is struggling to get market share based on technical advantage. At this point, it is about price and reputation of the company.  Speed, rewrites and software control add-one that balance number of write cycles across the whole array of registers are secondary because most vendors are about equal in those areas.

Answer (score 1):

Even when using an off-the-shelf controller, SSD manufacturers customize the firmware.

They have to at a bare minimum configure it with the amount of SDRAM and NAND flash on the PCB and to return the correct manufacturer and model number strings when queried.
Most adjust some tunable performance parameters.
Some add or modify significant features such as wear-leveling algorithms, TRIM support, full-disk encryption, etc.

Comment: Very interesting how you mention about custom firmware. I guess this explains why some generic SSD diagnostic tools like Crystal Disk Info can be so bad at diagnosing early indicators of failure?

Comment: @daikin: Crystal Disk Info relies on "[SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.)" data reported from the device.  If the on-board controller doesn't track all necessary parameters or even intentionally lies about failure counts, the analysis won't be useful.

Comment: A more severe issue is that many SSD failure modes have no early indicators.  Yes, worn out blocks accumulate slowly over time, but other things like data corruption in sector mapping tables can make a drive completely inaccessible after a single power event with no warning.  (If the firmware developers didn't write an algorithm to detect and recover from the corruption)

Comment: Very valid point about sector mapping. Any idea why no manufacturer diagnostic utilities are provided for enterprise-class SSDs (like those from Samsung) Yet, they provide a tool (Magician) for their personal users?

Comment: @daikin: Because enterprise users don't want to run a separate tool for every piece of hardware on their network, they want the hardware to report in conformance with a standard (for disk drives that's S.M.A.R.T.) so that a data aggregator can collect and process it all, providing the user with a central dashboard covering everything.  In fact each computer will probably aggregate data from its components (like disk S.M.A.R.T. data) into SNMP for centralized monitoring and alerting.

Comment: Thanks. That explains it. I often wondered about that. I do wonder though whether a generic SNMP tool would be as accurate as a manufacturer diagnostic tool esp. when it comes to SSDs?

Comment: @daikin: The accuracy of data depends on its source.  The source is the manufacturer firmware.  All that's changing is the user-facing presentation... and the best custom presentation in the world is not useful if it is shown to the wrong consumer.  In an enterprise environment, the local user is the wrong consumer.  (Besides which, Magician may be pretty, even glamorous, but its displays are nothing special from an information-theoretic viewpoint)

Comment: @daikin Also the SNMP tool has a big advantage over a vendor-specific tool... it sees the entire network and can spot outliers, both in value and in trend, that wouldn't have meaning evaluated in isolation.

Comment: Excellent point. I was totally forgetting about the scale advantage of SNMP tools - much easier to see the outliers. Thanks.